# What versions of SQL Server does Sharepoint 2010 and 2007 support?

Tags: 2010, 2007, sql-server

We have two SharePoint environments - 2010 and 2007.
We are looking to upgrade our SQL Cluster to SQL Server 2014 and are looking to see if 2010 and 2007 support it.  I could not find any recommendation on Microsoft's site.  If you know the answer, or if you have a link to the technet article that would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 is not supported on SQL 2014.  You can find the official Microsoft statement here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(v=office.14).aspx

In addition, based on the equation to determine compatibility in that document, SharePoint 2007 would not be supported on SQL 2014.

For the record, support for SharePoint 2013 on SQL 2014 began with the April 2014 CU:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/03/21/sql-server-2014-and-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx